# Turn Tabs on and off in Angular 2

Tags: angular, architecture

This is a weird question and I'm not quite sure how to phrase it.

What's the best way to turn on and off tabs in Angular 2? I have a settings screen where I want to be able to select features in a different configuration website. This would be saved in a database, where I can make api calls.

This app will be on computers in different locations. I want to be able to turn tabs on and off for that location. The landing page of this angular 2/4 app is a location selection. That will take you to another page that has tabs that you can use. Some places can reuse tabs, some have specific tabs for that location only.

So for example, location A would have access to tabs: "pictures, videos, comments" and location B would have acces to tabs: "pictures, comments, Location B specific tab"

This is more of an architecture question. In my opinion, it would be easier to create components and have a page that can display the components I allow (Factory method maybe?)

If possible, I would like to avoid having one component with functions that apply to every tab and an templateUrl page that has every tab coded and just hides it if it doesn't apply to the location.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a component for each of your tabs you may have, when you load the page you read the location, you fetch the list with the allowed tabs on that location from the api, you instantiate the tabs component with the allowed tabs, then fetch the data for each tab.